# String passed to data model from delegate results in object with delegate's class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I am quite new to objective-c, and am having a problem with some of my code for which I have been unable to find a solution on SO or elsewhere. I appreciate your patience.

Essentially, I have a model class which accesses data from my server, and two view controllers which serve as delegates on separate instances of the model, for which each view controller has been assigned as a delegate, respectively.

The first view controller (ListViewController) houses only a list, and data loads fine.

The second view controller (MapViewController) houses only a map. Herein lies the problem:

I create a URL in the view controller's viewDidLoad method as an NSString, and pass it to the model instance used by that view controller. In the model, the urlString is then converted to an NSURL, and the connection/data collection actuated. No data were being returned from the model.

After some debugging, I found that the urlString passed into the model's download would retain it's class as a string, but the jsonFileUrl variable would have the class MapViewController, rather than NSURL.

Here is some of my code.

#### DataModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DataModelProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items;

@end

@interface DataModel : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DataModelProtocol> delegate;

- (void)downloadItems:(NSString *)urlString;

@end
```

#### DataModel.m

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface DataModel() {
    NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}

@end

@implementation DataModel

- (void)downloadItems:(NSString *)urlString {

    //create url object with the link to download the json data
    //    THIS IS WHERE THE JSONFILEURL ENDS UP BECOMING MAPVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    //create the url request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

    //create connection to the url
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

... //functions to receive and parse results...
```

#### ListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DataModel.h"

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, DataModelProtocol>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listOneTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *var1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *var2;

@end
```

#### ListViewController.m

```
#import "ListViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface ListViewController () {
    DataModel *_dataModelInstance1; //data model to retrieve provider types
    NSArray *_feedItems; //array for provider types
    CustomClass *_selectedCustomInstance;
}

@end

@implementation ListViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set this view controller as the delegate and data source for the table view
    self.listOneTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listOneTableView.dataSource = self;

    //initialize an array object assigned to the pointer _feedItems
    _feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //create a new data model and assign it to _providerTypeDataModel
    _dataModelInstance1 = [[DataModel alloc] init];

    //set this view controller as the delegate for the _providerTypeDataModel object
    _dataModelInstance1.delegate = self;

    //call the downloadItems method of the _providerTypeDataModel object
    //  this will have the model download the data and organize it for us. afterwards, we need to handle it through the itemsDownloaded function
    NSString *downloadURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www....com/phpfile.php?var1=%@&var2=%@", self.var1, self.var2];

    [_dataModelInstance1 downloadItems:downloadURL]; //THIS ONE WORKS FINE
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items {

    _feedItems = items;
    [self.listOneTableView reloadData];
}

...//delegate methods and segue to MapViewController which passes var1, var2, and _selectedCustomInstance
```

#### MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <DataModelProtocol>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *var1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *var2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *selectedCustomInstance;

@end
```

#### MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "CustomClass.h"

@interface MapViewController () {
    DataModel *_dataModelInstance2;
    NSArray *_returnedArray;
}

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //initialize array for the provider list
    _returnedArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //create new datamodel for the provider list
    _dataModelInstance2 = [[DataModel alloc] init];

    //set this view controller as the delegate for the datamodel object
    _dataModelInstance2.delegate = self;

    //THIS STRING IS CREATED ACCURATELY, AND WHEN TESTED INDEPENDENTLY IN THE BROWSER, RETURNS THE DESIRED JSON
    NSString *downloadURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.....com/phpfile2.php?var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@", self.var1, self.var2, self.selectedCustomInstance];

    //THIS MODEL METHOD GETS CALLED, AND THE NSSTRING IS PASSED, BUT SUBSEQUENT CONVERSION TO NSURL RESULTS INSTEAD IN A MODELVIEWCONTROLLER CLASS OBJECT
    [_dataModelInstance2 downloadItems:downloadURL];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items {
    _returnedArray = items;
}

@end
```

Comment: Does the unwanted conversion happen immediately after the `jsonFileURL` is allocated, or only when the results are returned? If the latter, I think we need to see how the results are being parsed in DataModel to give a complete answer

Comment: `DataModel.m` would be the file in which the problem almost certainly exists.  It's the delegate to the `NSURLConnection` which is actually downloading the data, and you've failed to include any of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods that this class should have.

Comment: And since you haven't given us the actual URL's you're attempting to use, what's the difference between them?  Something could likely be encoding incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a guess since we have incomplete information, but it seems the only difference between the instance in which it works and the instance in which it doesn't work is the actual form of the URL.  This leads me to believe it's an encoding issue, since you're not encoding your strings.

Try adding, as the first line of `downloadItems:(NSString *)urlString;`, the following line:

```
urlString = [urlString sstringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```